# How to check the version of log4j used by a given slf4j?

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I have the slf4j jar, and inside it there's a pom with

```
<dependency>

  <groupId>log4j</groupId>

  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>

</dependency>
```

There's no version specified. Does that mean it's using the last version?

The jar name is slf4j-log4j12, does that mean it's using log4j 1.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep "log4j"
```

in your project, to see what version of log4j you are using.

As to your other question, "log4j12" does **not** mean version 1.2; see [maven.org](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.slf4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22slf4j-log4j12%22).

Comment: I'm seeing a `org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10` but this still doesn't tell me the real `log4j` version.

Comment: @FabianoLothor That is because in your case you are not using one. See [documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j).